# Converting a Json to include prepared statements for security. Just getting [] or undefined

Tags: php, sql, json, security, prepared-statement

Someone mentioned on a previous post that I need to use prepared statements in my php to protect from attacks. I'm trying to convert my documents but it seems to be breaking everything.

Here is my original code:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['number'])){
    $data = array();
    
    $dbHost     = '******';
    $dbUsername = '******';
    $dbPassword = '******';
    $dbName     = '******';
    
    $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
    if($db->connect_error){
        die("Unable to connect database: " . $db->connect_error);
    }
    
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE id = {$_POST['number']}");
    
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        $userData = $query->fetch_assoc();
        $data['status'] = 'ok';
        $data['result'] = $userData;
    }else{
        $data['status'] = 'err';
        $data['result'] = '';
    }
    
    echo json_encode($data);

}
?>
```

> UPDATE

This code shows data when I do a  `var_dump($response);`and the echo successfully displays on the PHP page with "success". However, I get nothing after `success:function(data)` on my ajax/jquery (no console logs work at all). What am I missing?

```
<?php
//dbconfig.php
    
    //database details
    $dbHost     = '****';
    $dbUsername = '****';
    $dbPassword = '****';
    $dbName     = '****';
 
    try{
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName",$dbUsername,$dbPassword);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 
    }catch(PDOException $z){
 
        die($z->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

---

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

$output = array();
$number= ($_POST['number']);   

$query = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE id = :id";
$response = $pdo -> prepare($query);  
$response->bindParam(':id', $number);

$response->execute();
var_dump($response);
if($response->execute()){  

$array = $response->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$output[] = $array;
$responseJSON = json_encode($output);
echo 'success';
header("Content-type: application/json;");
echo "$responseJSON";

$pdo = null;
}  else {
  $error="Error.";
  echo json_encode($error);

  }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

you are binding i but you never declare it

```
$idnum = $_POST['number'] // declare this below session_start it's much cleaner to see 

if ($stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM db WHERE id= :id ")) {
    $stmt->execute([':id' => $idnum]);
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
```

also you don't have error handler so you don't know what going wrong

```
    setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $exception) {
echo nl2br("PDO Exception \r\n");
echo nl2br('Error Code: ' . $exception->getCode() . "\r\n");
echo nl2br('Error Message: ' . $exception->getMessage() . "\r\n");
}
```

anyway this site teach you how to create PDO Prepared Statements and Connection from scratch  https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful and points me in the right direction. I'm going to give it a look later. One question, do I still need to bind_param?

Comment: it's optional goto this site https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection  and search the word  " controversial "

Comment: Interesting that the question is clearly using mysqli and yet the answer is using PDO.  This cannot work!

Comment: Just tried and it didn't work, but I'm learning about PDO from the page that was shared. It seems like it'll save many lines of code if I can figure it out. Perhaps I should have asked how to convert my query to PDO instead. Seems the tricky part is getting it to work with json.

Comment: @NigelRen he's trying to convert the 1st code snippet as PDO prepared statement and the 2nd code snippet is already half way converted as PDO prepared statement and not working  that is what the question is

Comment: The second code snippet is nothing to do with PDO - it's using `bind_param` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) which is the mysqli way of binding parameters.

Comment: Which would be better? The mysqli way, or the PDO way? From what I'm reading, PDO is quicker and cleaner. Are there any advantages to the mysqli way?